# Add condition to a Picklist field on Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, case, salesforce-lightning

I have two differents fields.

- Amount$ ( It is a text field from the Account Object)
- Priority ( It is a picklist field from the Case Object - you can choose [low, medium, high])

Basically, what I am trying to do is to add a condition to that Priority field based on the Amount field. If the Amount$ field is greater than 10 the value for Priority must be "High" IF NOT, I want the user to pick the value from the list.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you completed Trailhead modules on features like Validation Rules?

Comment: Hi! I finished that module and it is so interesting but they do not talk about the issue that I am facing! Because, in my case, I want to first evaluate the condition (evaluate how big is the amount of the other field) and if it is not TRUE, Then, I want to display the picklist field to let the user choose. I tried with validation rules and also I research on Formulas to accomplish it but no results. Thanks!